# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider' while working with background queue

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using Background task queues from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

In my startup.cs class I am adding the following:

```
 services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
 services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
```

all other services for the API are added like e.g. `services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();`

then in my controller I upload file, send it to blob storage and return `OK()` status, while starting the queue for processing file. It works fine until during the processing I want to update values in database:

```js
private void ProcessFile(string tempFilePath, FileFormatType fileFormat, IFormFile file, Type type, UploadData uploadData) {
  var delimiter = ",";
  Queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token => {
    // do the processing
    switch (type) {
      case Type.NewVersion:
        var headersMap = new NewersionHeaders();
        await ImportFile(tempFilePath, file.Length, uploadData.UserId, fileFormat, headersMap, delimiter ? ? ",", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        break;
    }
  });
}

private async Task ImportFile( string filePath, long fileSize, int userId, Type dataHeadersMap, string delimiter, string dateFormat) {
  using(var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var user = await _userRepository.Get(userId);
    uploadData.FileName = Path.GetFileName(stream.Name);

    // Log Unzipping time elapsed and unzipped file size
    stopwatch.Stop();
    uploadData.TimeElapsedUnzipping = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    uploadData.FileSizeUnzipped = stream.Length;
    stopwatch.Restart();

    await _uploadDataRepository.Add(uploadData);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    uploadData.TimeElapsedInserting = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    uploadData.UploadStatusType = UploadStatusType.Finished;
    await _uploadDataRepository.Update(uploadData);
  }
}
```

it fails on calling repositories `var user = await _userRepository.Get(userId)`/ `await _uploadDataRepository.Update(uploadData)`

with **exception**: 
 `Error occurred executing workItem.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.`

UserRepository.cs :

```js
public class UserRepository: BaseRepository < User > , IUserRepository {
  public UserRepository(IServiceProvider services): base(services) {}

  public async Task < User > GetByEmail(string email) {
    return await Store()
      .Filtered(nameof(User.Email), email)
      .FirstOrNull < User > ();
  }
}


// BaseRepository
namespace API.Repositories.Base {
  public abstract class BaseRepository < T > where T: class, IEntity, new() {
    protected readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public BaseRepository(IServiceProvider services) => _services = services;

    public virtual IDataStore Store() => _services.GetService < IDataStore > ().As < T > ();

    public async virtual Task < T > Add(T entity) => await Store().Add(entity);
  }
}

// injecting into service like:

public class ImportService: BaseService, IImportService {
  private readonly IUploadDataRepository _uploadDataRepository;
  private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
  public IBackgroundTaskQueue Queue {
    get;
  }
  private
  const string AZURE_BLOB_CONTAINER = "blobcontainer";

  public ImportService(IServiceProvider services, IBackgroundTaskQueue queue): base(services) {
    _uploadDataRepository = services.GetUploadDataRepository();
    _userRepository = services.GetUserRepository();
    Queue = queue;
  }
}



// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  //Add config file as singleton
  services.AddScoped(v => new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(_env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($ "appsettings.{_env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build());
  services.AddSingleton < IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor > ();
  var config = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService < IConfigurationRoot > ();

  services.Configure < ConfigurationSettings > (config);
  // Form file configuration to except large files
  services.Configure < FormOptions > (x => {
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
  });

  services.AddTransient(s => s.GetService < IOptions < ConfigurationSettings >> ().Value);

  // Repos and services
  ServiceExtensions.ConfigureServices(services, config);

  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(config);
  services.AddCors();

  var mvc = services.AddMvc(v => {
    // Order is important here!!
    v.Filters.Add < SessionTokenAuthenticateFilter > ();
    v.Filters.Add < SessionTokenAuthorizeFilter > ();
  });

  mvc.AddJsonOptions(
    opt => {
      opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
      opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter {
        CamelCaseText = true
      });
      opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnixDateTimeConverter());
      opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
      opt.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });

  // SQL
  services.AddScoped(v => {
    return new SqlConnection(config.GetDefaultConnection());
  });

  services.AddScoped < TransactionStore > ();

  services.AddScoped < SqlTransaction > (v => {
    var c = v.GetService < SqlConnection > ();

    if (c.State == ConnectionState.Broken || c.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      c.Open();

    var transaction = c.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    var transactionStore = v.GetRequiredService < TransactionStore > ();
    transactionStore.Transaction = transaction;
    return transaction;
  });
  services.AddSingleton < IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor > ();
  // Fluent migrator
  services
    .AddFluentMigratorCore()
    .ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
      .AddSqlServer2014()
      .WithGlobalConnectionString(config.GetDefaultConnection())
      // Define the assembly containing the migrations
      .ScanIn(typeof(M201807201046_FirstMigration).Assembly).For.Migrations())
    // Enable logging to console in the FluentMigrator way
    .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddFluentMigratorConsole())
    .BuildServiceProvider(false);

  // Migrate
  var servicesMigrationScope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
  UpdateDatabase(servicesMigrationScope);

  services.AddHostedService < QueuedHostedService > ();
  services.AddSingleton < IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue > ();

  // Hangfire
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new HangfireJobActivator(services));
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(config.GetDefaultConnection());
  services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseStorage(JobStorage.Current));

  // Hangfire Jobs
  //RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<DKVStrategy>(d => d.ImportBlacklist(), Cron.Daily(1, 30));

  // Register the Swagger services
  services.AddSwaggerDocument();
}

/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param>
/// <param name="env"></param>
/// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
  var config = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetConfig();
  loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);

  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  // Register the Swagger generator and the Swagger UI middlewares
  app.UseOpenApi();
  app.UseSwaggerUi3();

  app.UseMiddleware < ApiExceptionMiddleware > ();

  app.UseHsts();

  //if (env.IsDevelopment())
  app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins(config.Cors.Origins).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

  app.UseMvc();

  // The rest of the hangfire config
  app.UseHangfireServer();
  app.UseHangfireDashboard(
    "/hangfire",
    new DashboardOptions {
      Authorization = new [] {
        new HangfireDashboardFilter()
      }
    });
}
```

controller:

```js
namespace Api.Controllers {
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller for handling imports
    /// </summary>
    [SessionTokenAuthorize(SessionTokenType.Web)]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ImportController: BaseController {
      private readonly IImportService _importService;

      public ImportController(IServiceProvider services): base(services) {
        _importService = services.GetImportService();
      }

      [HttpPost("importFile")]
      [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
      public async Task < IActionResult > ImportFile(IFormFile file, Type type) {
        var userId = GetCurrentUserId();

        if (!userId.HasValue) {
          throw new CVTException(CVTExceptionCode.User.NotFound);
        }

        try {
          await _importService.UploadToBlobStorage(file, userId.Value, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return Ok();
      }


    }
```

Why can't call other repositories while working with queue and how to fix that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your constructor and show us how you initialize your repositories and worth to mention in hosted services there is no scope. You need to create your scope to access scoped services.

Answer (score 2):

In `QueuedHostedService` constructor import `IServiceProvider`

```
public QueuedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
 _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
```

Then in your `ImportFile` method create a scope from `IServiceProvider` and then get desired services with that scope.

```
private async Task ImportFile( string filePath, long fileSize, int userId, Type dataHeadersMap, string delimiter, string dateFormat) {
   using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
   {
     var userRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUserRepository>();
     // import other services
     // use them
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent creating scope inside the `ImportFile` method? there are more methods like that so I should find more a global solution and I call other methods inside these that also call repositories

Comment: @user122222 there is no way to avoid using scopes since your repositories are registered as scoped (and they should be). What you can do is move your logic (methods like ProcessFile and ImportFile) into a scoped service. Create a scope and in that scope instantiate the newly created scoped service and let it handle your logic.

Comment: @user122222 the link you added to your post has exact same sample [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)